# flash turning page effect

Tags: flash, transparency, effects

I have a html coded web page and I need to add a turning page effect to it.

I tryed several jQuery effects but none of them were good enough.

I´m thinking of using a transparented-background flash movie to get the effect, but I need to play and stop the flash movie from the html code.

I know how to show or hide it, but can I play it when showing and stop it when hiden??

If you have other ideas I´d love to hear them!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing the flash movie yourself?  If so you can use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to allow javascript in the page to signal the flash movie when to start/stop animating (and the movie could signal javascript when the animation is done).